# monaco editor autocompletions not including this properties correctly

Tags: javascript, monaco-editor

When I use autocompletions in the monaco editor, `this` member variables don't seem to autocomplete correctly. For example:

```
function myFunc() {
    this.foo = []
    this.foo. // I would expect autocompletions here
    var bar = []
    bar. // this works, showing array methods, etc
}
```

How can I get the this member variables to also show up in autocompletions?